# '[code]' shortcode to markup programming code does not work

Tags: embed, code

I have been trying to embed some simple code on a practice blog and it has no effect other than to display the tag as text.
I am aware there is no code in the image but believe me I have tried. 
The images are from the code in the text editor on the dashboard and the other is a preview of the saved changes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: WordPress doesn’t have a `[code]` shortcode. You would need a plugin or theme that provides it.

Comment: what about this... https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

Comment: WordPress **.com**. The WordPress.com service has features that the self hosted version doesn’t have. Some of them are available in the Jetpack plugin. I don’t know if this is one of them.